# Java library for threshold signatures

Tags: java, cryptography

I need a library that implements threshold cryptography. The idea is to use the technique in a replicated system implemented in Java.

So far, I have only found [ThresSig](http://threshsig.sourceforge.net/) (which implements Shoup's Practical Threshold Signatures) and the ECDSA implementation used in [TwoFactorBtcWallet](https://github.com/citp/TwoFactorBtcWallet). However, I am not sure if ThresSig is a recomendable option, and even though the aforementioned ECDSA implementation is recent, I can't figure out how to use it for what I need. In addition, both options are lacking on documentation. Are there any other (functional) threshold signature libraries besides these two?